# Working vs walking on both sides of the street

Tags: meaning, idioms, word-usage

Dictionary.com renders "work both sides of the street" as:

> To take two contrary positions at once; have it both ways

Similarly, idiom.thefreedictionary.com has "work both sides of the street" as:

> Engage in double dealing, be duplicitous

On the other hand, Urbandictionary.com renders the similar idiom to "walk both sides of the street" as:

> Country slang for a bisexual

Is the differentition between working and walking accepted? Compare (http://www.patheos.com/blogs/thoughtfulpastor/2013/06/13/more-on-the-epic-battle-between-good-and-evil/?repeat=w3tc)

> Severus Snape–a man who had to walk on both sides of the street.

In short, does walking both sides of the street necessarily carry sexual connotations?

Comment: Personally, I am not familiar with the phrase "walking both sides of the street," but I can see why some people think it has a sexual connotation, just as "his door swings both ways" manages to communicate a similar thought.

Comment: I've heard both uses, and both used to describe sexual and non-sexual ideas.

Comment: An entry in Urban Dictionary simply tells you that at some point a single person decided to put an entry in for a word or phrase.  They might be the only person in the world for whom the word or phrase has that specific meaning.  You shouldn't take it too seriously.

Comment: As other moderators here have argued, sometimes these social/collective web sites have merit if they might not be correct.

Comment: Euphemisms are very flexible. If you're in a context where someone's sexuality is being described, practically any phrase that involves two-sidedness will be understood to mean bisexual. We don't need set phrases (although some become popular), any metaphor will work.

Comment: "work both sides of the street" could equally have sexual connotations. I'm not sure what work you're doing on the street, but one possibility would be prostitution.

Answer (score 3):

No, neither of the phrases is necessarily sexual.

For example a 04 April 1906 [conversation](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Metric_System/IB8yAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22english%20system%22%20%22working%20both%20sides%20of%20the%20street%22&pg=PA39&printsec=frontcover) in the US House Committee on Coinage, Weights and Measures was:

> Mr. Wood: The English system is taught in German schools?
> Mr. Monaghan: Yes, sir.
> Mr. Gaines: Why?
> Mr. Monaghan: For the purpose of giving them the advantage of what others have.
> Mr. Gaines: Working both sides of the street ?

And 25 April 1955 in the US Senate Mr. Fulbright [said this](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Congressional_Record/1ubq7njVwzoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22walking%20both%20sides%20of%20the%20street%22&pg=PA5002&printsec=frontcover) about Time Magazine:

> *Time* accuses me of walking both sides of the street successfully, of conforming to my constituents, and of knowing how to tip my hat to southern industrialists.